# OpenJPA: Code to build entities automatically from DB

Tags: java, database, orm, entity, openjpa

Hi I'm looking for a code/tool to generate entities automatically. I'm not looking for a software like eclipselink which has to be executed manually, but rather a piece of code (or a maven plugin) that can be automatically run whenever the db changes.  (If I can autorun eclipselink via cron job, that would work for me.)

Some other options:

1. I think Hibernate offers a reverse engineering method that can be called from maven build that auto generates the entities from db schemas. Does anyone has a such a tool for openjpa.
2. Any command line utility where you just specify the db urls and options and the utility generates the entities. I can just write a cron to run the utility nightly etc.
3. Any software that can be called automatically via cron, and it generates the entity will also do.

Update:
OpenJPA Reverse mapping tool seems to really suck at generating a proper entity with annotations, mapping and so on... I would be glad if someone corrected me

Comment: You mean back porting from database structure into Java entities?

Comment: Correct. We have developers changing the dbs during development. And we just need a system that runs like every night and builds all the java entities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [Reverse Mapping](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/latest/docs/manual/manual.html#ref_guide_pc_reverse) in the user manual. You can launch that from an ant task.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt a **fully automatized** tool like that can exist — simply because it can't be done well without human intervention. How would, for example, the algorithm decide which attributes should be taken into account in `equals()` and `hashCode()`? Or new relations uni- or bidirectional? Lazy/eager loading? And so on.

As you know, and others have noted, the tools per se exist, but they're rather intended to run once, tweak the result, and work with it from now on, rather than be a part of a continous integration process.

Comment: Why not? Tools like elipselink do essentially the same thing. I just need to run , say eclipselink , automatically.

Comment: By eclipselink I mean the one I have in Netbeans. I have yet to experiment with the other eclipselink.

Comment: @SQC **Semiautomatically**. They **propose** mapping options for you to choose from, that's not the same thing.

Comment: @MaDa.. Perhaps you're right(+1), but that is not the point of my question. I have changed the question a bit. That should give you a clearer picture of what I am looking for. thanks for the interest.

Comment: +1. @SQC: the entities will be the core of your application. They should be designed and documented with care. And they should also contain methods and not just getters and setters. They should provide encapsulated services.  Some entities might have to extend other classes or entities or implement interfaces. Don't let an automatic tool create them for you.